# mgcv bam() summary tables differ by computer RAMs

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm using the mgcv (1.8-40) bam() function with discrete==TRUE method to fit in GAM for a very large dataset. It occurs that the summary table and results of the same fitted model differ by computer RAMs (cluster vs PC). I'm using the [Fraud Detection - Credit Card](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yashpaloswal/fraud-detection-credit-card/download?datasetVersionNumber=1) data from Kaggle to generate reproducible examples below:

```
library(mgcv)
library(mgcViz)
credit<-data.table::fread("creditcard.csv")
bam3<-bam(class~s(V2)+s(V3)+s(V4)+s(V6)+s(V8)+s(V10)+
            s(V11)+s(V12)+s(V13)+s(V14)+s(V15,V18)+s(V16)+s(V17)+
            s(V21)+s(V22)+s(V23)+s(V27), family=binomial(link = "logit"),
          data=credit, discrete=TRUE, select=TRUE)
summary(bam3)
#use mgcviz to visualize results
t <- getViz(bam3)
print(plot(t, allTerms = T, trans = function(x){ 
  plogis(coef(bam3)[1] + x)}, seWithMean = TRUE, ylab="Fraud probability"), pages = 1)
```

Here are the summary table and result plots when running the model on my PC and a cluster with smaller RAM:

```
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
class ~ s(V2) + s(V3) + s(V4) + s(V6) + s(V8) + s(V10) + s(V11) + 
    s(V12) + s(V13) + s(V14) + s(V15, V18) + s(V16) + s(V17) + 
    s(V21) + s(V22) + s(V23) + s(V27)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -8.946      2.686   -3.33 0.000867 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
              edf Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
s(V2)      2.9980      9  21.478 4.92e-06 ***
s(V3)      0.6508      9   1.137  0.13907    
s(V4)      4.6965      9 163.282  < 2e-16 ***
s(V6)      2.8267      9  10.310  0.00635 ** 
s(V8)      3.3933      9  69.022  < 2e-16 ***
s(V10)     2.9709      9  59.061  < 2e-16 ***
s(V11)     4.7405      9  30.051 2.37e-06 ***
s(V12)     4.2906      9  77.346  < 2e-16 ***
s(V13)     0.8916      9   8.225  0.00193 ** 
s(V14)     6.2394      9 171.185  < 2e-16 ***
s(V15,V18) 9.9426     29  32.406 1.26e-05 ***
s(V16)     0.8480      9   5.578  0.00729 ** 
s(V17)     1.3670      9   4.075  0.02791 *  
s(V21)     1.1263      9   7.574  0.00196 ** 
s(V22)     0.7039      9   2.377  0.05558 .  
s(V23)     0.6409      9   1.785  0.08236 .  
s(V27)     0.6212      9   1.024  0.16234    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.77   Deviance explained = 81.2%
fREML = 2.625e+05  Scale est. = 1         n = 284807
```

[image]

Compared to the summary table and result plots when running the model on a cluster with larger RAM (>80G):

```
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
class ~ s(V2) + s(V3) + s(V4) + s(V6) + s(V8) + s(V10) + s(V11) + 
    s(V12) + s(V13) + s(V14) + s(V15, V18) + s(V16) + s(V17) + 
    s(V21) + s(V22) + s(V23) + s(V27)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -8.946      2.596  -3.446 0.000569 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
s(V2)      3.000e+00      9  21.705 4.87e-06 ***
s(V3)      3.774e-05      9   0.000  0.16275    
s(V4)      4.655e+00      9 163.440  < 2e-16 ***
s(V6)      2.708e+00      9  10.098  0.00639 ** 
s(V8)      3.493e+00      9  69.669  < 2e-16 ***
s(V10)     3.035e+00      9  63.367  < 2e-16 ***
s(V11)     4.799e+00      9  31.079 1.72e-06 ***
s(V12)     4.271e+00      9  76.626  < 2e-16 ***
s(V13)     8.950e-01      9   8.525  0.00164 ** 
s(V14)     6.203e+00      9 174.908  < 2e-16 ***
s(V15,V18) 9.921e+00     29  32.000 1.53e-05 ***
s(V16)     8.395e-01      9   5.230  0.00907 ** 
s(V17)     1.390e+00      9   4.173  0.02693 *  
s(V21)     1.139e+00      9   7.847  0.00167 ** 
s(V22)     7.100e-01      9   2.448  0.05325 .  
s(V23)     6.571e-01      9   1.916  0.07646 .  
s(V27)     6.770e-01      9   1.159  0.15171    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.77   Deviance explained = 81.2%
fREML = 2.625e+05  Scale est. = 1         n = 284807
```

[image]

Note the difference in coefficients of each covariates, especially V3, V6, V12, V13, V15*V18, V16, V17.

This is not the best model to fit the data, but I chose it to replicate the issue that I've been experiencing with my own data. I'm puzzled by the different results on different machines, and would like to know which are the more reliable ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those models don't look that different beyond some small differences in the EDFs of some estimated smooths that, at least from the plots (which are hard to interpret because of the large credible intervals - perhaps consider transforming some of the those covariates), don't look qualitatively different.

GAMs in {mgcv} use some very efficient algorithms that make extensive use of linear algebra routines. This is especially so for `bam()` with `discrete = TRUE`. Those linear algebra routines can be sensitive to the particular brand of BLAS / LAPACK that is installed and also to the specific CPU on which R is running.

As you are seeing differences on different clusters, I would investigate what BLAS / LAPACK is on each system, as well as a confirming that you have the same version of R and {mgcv} on both.

But from what I can see, those two models would be telling you the same thing qualitatively, despite some minor differences in the details of the fits. Those differences are extremely unlikely to be statistically or scientifically significant.

Comment: +1 for the BLAS/LAPACK. When in my field we find a difference between PC/cluster solutions on GAM unrelated problems it is usually because of different BLAS/LAPACK versions.

Comment: @rep_ho +1 As someone who maintains an R package that depends on {mgcv} I face these trivial differences all the time on CRAN's various test machines and it is almost always BLAS/LAPACK related.

Comment: Thank you both! The BLAS/LAPACK version of the clusters that I've been using is /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.15.so, which is different from my PC. However, this doesn't explain the difference between clusters. Could it be the different CPUs(broadwell, skylake or cascade)?  Also, in the BLAS thread safety section of the mgcv manual, it says "Most BLAS implementations are thread safe, but some versions of OpenBLAS, for example, are not." Does this suggest that BLAS is preferable over the openBLAS on cluster? I also added my results to the question. It would be great to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Also, the {mgcv} version is the same (mgcv_1.8-40) across all systems. I have R version 4.2.1 on my PC, and it's R version 4.1.3 for both clusters. @GavinSimpson

Comment: Here is a post (https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/2164) from Simon Wood about thread safety of OpenBLAS 0.3.X. I tried to implement the solution he recommended (make USE_THREAD=0 USE_LOCKING=1) but had no luck yet, but it might be a useful reference.

Answer (score 1):

To build up on the great answer from @Gavin Simpson, one can check the BLAS/LAPACK version in R through `sessionInfo()`. If there are multiple versions on the cluster, you can choose one of them by using LD_PRELOAD trick via the bash script:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.15.so
```

Dr. Simon Wood provided further insights on how BLAS version might affect the mgcv output:

"Different BLAS optimizations order computations differently. The computations are mathematically equivalent, of course, but different ordering leads to slightly different rounding errors in floating point arithmetic. Occasionally such a tiny difference can get amplified to a noticeable effect if the model is not statistically very stable. Logistic regression in regions where the response are all zeroes or all ones is an example. Another thing that can happen is that just occasionally a tiny difference leads to the optimizer meeting the convergence criterion a step earlier on one BLAS version than another, and this actually making a difference - that one can be spotted by looking at how many optimization steps have been taken, and is usually fixed by tightening convergence tolerances. Of course it is also sometimes possible that the REML criterion used for smoothing parameter selection has developed more than one optimum, and different actual optima have been located."